# Swing Table not rendering properly

Tags: java, swing, javafx

This is the code to create a table using `swing`.

```
var colNames: Object[] = ["S.No.", "Item Name", "Formulation", "Dosage" , "Batch No.", "Expiry", "MRP", "Purchase price","Selling Price", "Qty", "T.Qty", "R.Qty", "Foo", "Bar"];
var colType: Class[] = [java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class,
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class,
                 java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class,
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class];

var colEditable: Boolean[]= [false, false, false, false, false, false, false,  false, false, false, true, false, false, false];
var colWidth: Integer[] = [35, 50, 120, 75, 40, 66, 56, 50, 46, 40,40, 40, 0, 0];
var cashTable = CashSalesTableObj.createTable(rowNo, colNames, colType, colEditable, colWidth, "Sales");
```

This works perfectly . But i want to delete the last two coloumns `Foo`, `Bar` .. If I do like below,

```
var colNames: Object[] = ["S.No.", "Item Name", "Formulation", "Dosage" , "Batch No.", "Expiry", "MRP", "Purchase price","Selling Price", "Qty", "T.Qty", "R.Qty"];
var colType: Class[] = [java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class,
                java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class,
                 java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class,
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.Integer.class];

var colEditable: Boolean[]= [false, false, false, false, false, false, false,  false, false, false, true, false];
var colWidth: Integer[] = [35, 50, 120, 75, 40, 66, 56, 50, 46, 40,40, 40];
var cashTable = CashSalesTableObj.createTable(rowNo, colNames, colType, colEditable, colWidth, "Sales");
```

It won't work. Columns are not rendered properly.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be java... Is it scala?

Comment: it's javafx.... But the values are passed from `.jx` file to `.java` file

Comment: any suggestion or hint.

Comment: I will check the size of the arrays first. On an iPad

Comment: Sorry, I have never seen this syntax before, even with JavaFX. I can't help.

Comment: @BackSlash it's  old `javafx 1.3` code.. Is this related to table height or width?

Comment: 1. JTable.removeColumn(TableColumn aColumn), column is still presents in XxxTableModel, is invisible but accesible from models view, 2. It won't work. Columns are not rendered properly. - for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, 3. if colWidth is about set(Preferred)Size to columns from ColumnModel, then doesn't zero (0) value works there is still minimal size around/close to  10pixels